# How to pass around variables without url parameters in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, url-parameters

My question is, how could I go about passing information in django from the template to a view without url parameters. I know that sessions can help me do this however, I can't find any resources online that show how to create a key value pair in the sessions from within a template. For example, If I had a link

```
<a href= "{% url .....%}">{{ c.class_id }}</a>
```

which would lead you to a specific university class homepage, how could I pass along `c.class_id` to the view that is responsible for rendering this specific homepage? Would I have to put this link inside a form and then POST it to the view?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it with a URL parameter?

Comment: Trying to avoid having too many url parameters. I have already implemented what I need with url parameters however, I had to pass around all the parameters that were in the url, even the ones I no longer need. For example, if I had a clasd_id parameter and a assignment_id parameter in my url and I was working in an addisnment view, I no longer need the class_id parameter but django required me to still pass it around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GET parameters. Example:

```
<a href= "{% url .....%}?class_id={{c.class_id}}">{{ c.class_id }}</a>
```

To retrieve the parameter from the Django view, use:

```
param_value = request.GET['param_name']
```

Comment: Say for example my url was  "class/assignments", would it now have to be "class/assignments?class_id = ......" ?

Comment: Yes, that is it. But no spaces around the `=`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string for more info. To access the parameter from a Django view, use `request.GET['parameter_name']`.